# Cancel build in drone.io

Tags: timeout, continuous-integration, cancellation, drone.io

I'm working on setting Drone.io into repositories of my team, in order to have continuous integration.

The problem is I have a test build locked and I see no way to cancel it. Is there a way to cancel it manually? If not, is there a timeout that causes the build expire?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A running Build can be canceled manually any time via Link/Button on status page. There is also an 15 min. fixed Timeout on free plans (see Limits: http://docs.drone.io/buildscript.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can kill a build using drone-cli command, see https://discourse.drone.io/t/how-to-kill-a-build-stuck-in-running-state/1022/2 for details.

Note: You should use the same version for drone-cli and drone-server/agent

Answer (score 0):

You could cancel a drone build using `drone build stop`:

```
drone build stop octocat/hello-world 1
```

Or could forcefully kill the build using `drone build kill`:

```
drone build kill octocat/hello-world 1
```